# Laplacian of complex function proof

Tags: complex-analysis, laplacian

If $f \in C^2$(as a two variable real function) and $\Delta f = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}$ then 
$$\Delta f = 4 \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z \partial \overline{z}} = 4 \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial \overline{z} \partial z} $$

I tried playing with Cauchy-Riemann equations:

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)
$$

applying $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$

$$
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial \overline{z} \partial z} = \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} +i \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y \partial x} + i\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y} - \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} \right)
$$

But that leads nowhere.

It does not look like a hard task though, how can we prove it?

Comment: Calculating $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{(\partial \overline z)^2}$ won't result in the same thing as $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z\partial \overline z}$

Comment: Oh, you're right. I actually did $\partial \overline{z}$ twice by mistake. If I do that with respect to z(as I have written) it works! Thank you for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the complex case

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} &= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right) \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}} &= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)
\end{align}

then you get 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial\bar{z}} =\frac{1}{4}\Big(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\Big)
\end{equation}

I think you are looking for the Wirtinger derivatives ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives ).